# One DIV with two Google maps, similar to an image gallery

Tags: google-maps, gallery

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a "gallery", but instead of pictures, I have two addresses from Google Maps.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just create two map instances!

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="map1"></div>
    <div id="map2"></div>
    <style>
      html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      #map1, #map2 {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      var map1, map2;
      function initMap() {
        map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });

        map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```